# How to make xaml StringFormat update with CurrentCulture

Tags: wpf, localization, string-formatting

I'm making a calendar in WPF and I want this calendar to be able to translate to any language. The StringFormat is translating month names the first time (with the CurrentCulture of its first loading) but won't update after that if I change the CurrentCulture again.

I tried to notify change on the DateTime property but WPF won't update the language. If I create a String property returning a DateTime.ToString("format") or use a Converter to return a DateTime.ToString("format") it works.

Is there no way to make it work only with XAML?

Comment: You could set the ConverterCulture property of the binding, but that won't update once you set it.